# how to post with form-data only with retrofit

Tags: android, postman, retrofit, retrofit2, form-data

I try to post data and get the response with POST using retrofit. In postman it works fine but in code it error.

this is the last thing I tried

service

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("program/get/list-user-program")
fun getProgram(
        @Field("comunity") comunity:String,
        @Field("programGroupUrl") programGroupUrl:Int
): Call<ListProgramResponse>
```

activity

```
 val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        val apiService: Service = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

val call: Call<ListProgramResponse> = apiService.getProgram("abc", 0)

call.enqueue(object : Callback<ListProgramResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ListProgramResponse>, response: Response<ListProgramResponse>) {
Log.e("check", response.body()?.toString())

override fun onFailure(call: Call<ListProgramResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
```

response

```
 data class ProgramBersedekahResponse(
    @SerializedName("banner") val banner: String?,
    @SerializedName("domainlembaga") val domainlembaga: String?,
    @SerializedName("domainprogram") val domainprogram: String?,
    @SerializedName("donate") val donatur: Int?
)
```

but it says `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` and failure. did anyone know why? please help

Comment: what is the json response you are getting in post man ?

Comment: I already add the question. you can see it now